# Microphone not working using skype

Tags: sound, skype, microphone

Ok. Before posting this I tried every solution already offered before (unless I missed something).

My internal microphone is not working. I tried silencing front right via pavucontrol, tried to define the input device as alsa through gstremer-properties, unchecked "allow skype to automaticly adjust my mixer settings", checked if the microphone was muted.
I have no idea what else to do. any help would be appriciated. thanks.

Comment: Does the microphone work in other applications? If not then can you put the output of `lspci -v | grep -i audio` so we know what soundcard you're using and then put the result of `arecord -l` up so we know if the microphone is being picked up...

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)  and run :

```
gstreamer-properties
```

[image]

Change the settings under **Default Input** to the below screenshot.

[image]

Close the **gstreamer-properties** and plugin your mic to see if its working.

Note: If its still not working then you may have to try giving different Device inputs  under Default Input.

Comment: I don't have that option.
the only option other than default I have is "cirrus analog" and that doesn't help.
Also, I use an internal mic.

Comment: And I tried all the device inputs. none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by removing the line microphone from computer back in and reconnected it on computer on front microphone in. Now it works fine.

Comment: Well, since I've been trying to use my internal microphone ad not an external one, I couldn't really switch the connection point..